# Typescript issue with API result not assigning to typed variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have recently started learning Angular and Typescript and I was building a small test application that would call data from an existing local Web API that serves HR data. I checked via Fiddler to make sure that the API is returning the dataset I am expecting and the data is fine. I created a component and service to take these results and assign them to an Employee interface seen below:

```
export interface Employee {
    department: string;
    departmentId: number;
    email: string;
    employeeId: number;
    firstName: string;
    hireDate: string;
    jobId: number;
    lastName: string;
    manager: string;
    managerId: number;
    phoneNumber: string;
    salary: number;
    title: string;
}
```

and the data I am receiving from the API looks like this:

```
[{…}]
0
: 
department
: 
null
departmentId
: 
6
email
: 
"bruce.ernst@sqltutorial.org"
employeeId
: 
5
firstName
: 
"Bruce"
hireDate
: 
"5/21/1991"
jobId
: 
9
lastName
: 
"Ernst"
manager
: 
null
managerId
: 
2
phoneNumber
: 
"590.423.4568"
salary
: 
6000
title
: 
null
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

That data is pulled via this service code *employee.service.ts*:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Employee } from '../Interfaces/employee';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {     
  }

  getEmployeeById(id: number): Observable<Employee> {
    const employee = this.http.get<Employee>("http://localhost:200/api/Employee/GetEmployeeById?id=" + id);
    return employee;
  }
}
```

My Employeedetail component for taking the data and assigning it to inputs is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../Interfaces/employee';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { EmployeeService } from '../services/employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employeedetail',
  templateUrl: './employeedetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employeedetail.component.css']
})
export class EmployeedetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() employee?: Employee;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployee();
  }

  getEmployee(): void {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(id)
      .subscribe(e => { 
        console.log(e);  
        this.employee = e;        
      });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

In the line **console.log(e)**, I get the value I am expecting when I view it in the devtools on the browser, but when I assign it with the line **this.employee = e**, I get "undefined" for everything. I do not get any errors at all.

I am sure that this is something simple that I am just overlooking as I have been jumping back and forth between this and some other React/TS code, but for whatever reason I am not seeing it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if I am missing any code that would help explain the issue.

Comment: Remove the `Input` decorator from your employee variable. You only use the `Input` decorator when you pass data from the parent to the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are getting an array of one object in your response :

```
[{…}]
0
: 
department
:
```

In this case, update your service method with correct type:

```
const employee = this.http.get<Employee[]>("http://localhost:200/api/Employee/GetEmployeeById?id=" + id);
```

and the assignement of your variable as well

```
this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(id)
      .subscribe(e => { 
        console.log(e);  
        this.employee = e[0];        
      });
```

Comment: Lol. I knew it had to be something like this. Thanks for the extra set of eyes on this!